# Do my children need any kind of identification if we are flying inside the UK?

Tags: air-travel, uk, paperwork, children

I kind of remember advice about having an ID when you fly even if you are traveling within your home country. My children are still young and have no ID apart from their birth certificates.

Comment: Which airline? ..

Comment: @AE BA, it's the best choice for a short trip within the UK in my opinion

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most airlines have a bit about this on their site - for example, on [RyanAir](https://www.ryanair.com/us/questions/do-i-need-a-visa/), for travel in the UK:

Adults:

> Any photo ID which matches the passenger name in the booking.

Infants and Children:

> Children under 16 years of age (travelling with an adult) on UK
>   domestic flights can travel without photo identification.

So no, they don't need ID to travel in the UK, as long as they're travelling with you.